# ConcurrentModificationException in Java List when using Object and Duplicate List

Tags: java, list, function, class, arraylist

I am using Java to iterate a list and update it based on certain criteria. But since it will provide `ConcurrentModificationException` im using a duplicate list for this but this still provides the same exception.

I have a class named `Storage` that denotes a virtual storage that is represented as a folder (one folder for one storage) and this class contains an attribute `fileList` that denotes the list of files it contains (within the folder). The class is as given below,

```
public class Storage
{
    // List of files in storage
    private List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>();

    // Occupied size in MB
    private double occupiedStorage;

    // Location of storage folder
    private String location;

    public Storage(String loca) // Create a storage
    {
        this.location = loca;
        this.occupiedSize = 0;
    }

    public addFile(File f) // Add file to storage
    {
        // Copy the file to folder in location 'this.location'
        this.fileList.add(f);
        this.occupiedSize = this.occupiedSize + f.length()/1048576.0;
    }

    public List<File> getFilesList() // Get list of files in storage
    {
        return this.filesList;
    }

    public double getOccupiedSize() // Get the occupied size of storage
    {
        return this.occupiedSize;
    }
}
```

I have created a total of 10 storage using 10 objects and each of them has separate folders. The i added many different files to all the folders using for loop and calling the `this.addFile(f)` function.

Then later i want to delete only specific files from specific storages that satisfy a certain criteria and i added the following deletion function to the `Storage` class,

```
public void updateFileList()
{
    List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
    files = this.getFilesList();
    for (File f : files)
    {
        if (/*Deletion criteria satisfied*/)
        {
            f.delete();
            this.getFilesList().remove(f);
            this.occupiedSize = this.occupiedSize - f.length()/1048576.0;
        }
    }
}
```

But this provides `ConcurrentModificationException` in the `Enhanced For Loop` that i am using in the `updateFileList()` function. Within the enhanced for loop i am updating the `this.getFilesList()` list by removing the unwanted file, and the iteration is made using a duplicate list `files`. Then why am i getting the `ConcurrentModificationException` exception?? Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove an element from a list with `remove()` while iterating. But You can do this by using an iterator:

```
    public void updateFileList() {
        List<File> files = this.getFilesList();
        Iterator<File> iter = files.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            File f = iter.next();
            if (/*Deletion criteria satisfied*/)
            {
                f.delete();
                iter.remove();
                this.occupiedSize = this.occupiedSize - f.length()/1048576.0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use ListIterator rather than using for each . and use method iterator.remove to remove a file from  a list.

```
public void updateFileList()
{
    List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
    files = this.getFilesList();
     Iterator<File> it = files.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {

            if (deletion condition) {

                it.remove();

            }
        }
}
```

also read about fail-fast and fail-safe iterator in java  link is here [fail-fast and fail-safe iterator in java](http://javaconceptoftheday.com/fail-fast-and-fail-safe-iterators-in-java-with-examples/)

Answer (score 0):

You are removing element from the list while iterating through the list.

Try changing the `getFilesList()` method from

```
public List<File> getFilesList() // Get list of files in storage
{
    return this.filesList;
}
```

to

```
public List<File> getFilesList() // Get list of files in storage
{
    return new ArrayList<File>(this.filesList);
}
```